# Populating List from Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program that screen scrapes a handful of pages using HtmlAgilityPack and I want it to run faster, as the Load for the pages can take 1-2 seconds on occasion. Right now I have below code that does it sequentially.

```
  List<Projections> projectionsList = new List<Projections>();       
  for (int i = 532; i <= 548; i++)
            {
                doc = webGet.Load("http://myurl.com/projections.php?League=&Position=97&Segment=" + i + "&uid=4");
                GetProjection(doc, ref projectionsList, (i));
            }
```

Basically I wan to break out the code inside the loop to multiple threads and wait till all threads complete before executing. I would expect the List to be populated when complete. I realize Lists are not thread safe, but I am a little stuck on figuring out how to get around that.

Comment: Does `webGet` have async methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use a Parallel.For as the example of @Tgys, but you can use a [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) collection, which is thread safe and you don't need to handle locks.

```
ConcurrentBag<Projections> projectionsList = new ConcurrentBag<Projections>();       
Parallel.For(532, 548 + 1, i => {
    var doc = webGet.Load("http://myurl.com/projections.php?League=&Position=97&Segment=" + i + "&uid=4");    
    GetProjection(doc, ref projectionsList, (i));
    }
});
```

Probably you need to change your GetProjection method. So check if my solution fit your needs.

See this [link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_ConcurrentBagT) for more info about ConcurrentBag class.

Comment: Was it useful for you?

Comment: yes it was, but I am running into another threading issue. I need to iterate over 2 collections, which total to about 2.3MM iterations and the process is doing a ton (modifying collections, calculations) and takes about 1.3 hours. I want to implement Parallel.ForEach but when I do so, it is not any faster, as I imagine I am either doing something wrong or it is not the use case for it. Any thoughts on this with the small amount of info I gave you? :)

Comment: @IsaacLevin If your process takes 1.3 hours, it doesn't means that it's wrong necessarily. How many time does it takes with a normal ForEach?... However, it seems that you have a heavy logic with so many tasks, so maybe you can consider to convert it in a long running process. Check http://hangfire.io/, with it you can trigger a process in the backend and then you can give the feedback to the user when the process finishes (an email or notification maybe). Hope my opinion can help you.

Comment: The process is the same time with simple for each, so it doesn't seem to be working properly. I will take a look at hangfire.io but I would like to make the process fasterling if possible.

Comment: @IsaacLevin Anotther suggestion: if you can make your process in some different steps, check it out the producer/consumer pattern. You can implement it in .NET using a BlockingCollection class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx. This is also a way of making some parallel tasks at the same time. However, it depends a lot of what you need, so you have to evaluate it. Check it and try it if you can. Regards.

Comment: When you mean different steps are you referring to process flow? Basically what the process has is 2 nested loops with thousands of records each, and multiple loops at a much smaller level to perform specific tasks. Where would I put the BlockingCollection?

Answer (score 0):

Use for example the Parallel for loop to create a basic concurrent loop. Then, whenever manipulating the list, make sure you lock the list first so other no two threads can manipulate it at once.

```
List<Projections> projectionsList = new List<Projections>();       
Parallel.For(532, 548 + 1, i => {
    var doc = webGet.Load("http://myurl.com/projections.php?League=&Position=97&Segment=" + i + "&uid=4");
    lock (projectionsList) {
        GetProjection(doc, ref projectionsList, (i));
    }
});
```